# How to auto post an image from gallery in facebook by clicking a button in flutter application?

Tags: facebook, post, flutter, dart

I am building an application which will post automatically an image from the gallery. But in my case when I click post button it is going to the "Compose post page" of Facebook.

I want to post directly in my facebook account without going to the compose post page.

Comment: If by _“in my facebook account”_ you are referring to your personal _user profile_ - that is not possible any more; you can only post to Facebook _pages_ via API.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be using the facebook API. Because you haven't given me any code, I'm not sure exactly what you are doing - but I imagine you need to have a button that will call the facebook API [according to this documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/)

For example:

```
...
GestureDetector(
 onTap: () =>
   postToFacebook(),
 child: Button("Post image"),
),
...

...
void PostToFacebook() async {
  await http.post('https://graph.facebook.com/<your page>/pictures?url=path/to/picture&caption=Hello&access_token=<your access token>')
}
```

Comment: How to get access_token?

Comment: Create an app on developers.facebook.com, and it will give you an API key.